# Visualizing infinitesimals

Tags: calculus, visualization

I am having problems visualizing infinitesimals. Like in a curve, when we integrate we can adjust in it a perfect infinitely thin rectangle. But how do I visualize it? Every time I try to visualize it, I always notice some gap area or error in the curve. Also in differentiation, $ dx $ is supposed to an infinitely close step. But every time I draw a line, I can cut it into smaller line and that becomes $ dx $. So I am facing bit problema visualizing infinitesimals.

Comment: Think of them as a process, not an object. You can imagine your rectangle as shrinking forever, and that "final object" being what we work with.

Comment: Note the whole calculus can be rigorously defined without using infinitesimals. Thus, strictly speaking, you don't *need* to visualise them. In fact, with that approach you don't have an entity "$dx$". You do have things called $dy/dx$ but this is not a ratio - but a different symbol for something we can call $y'(x)$. there are no "infinitely small positive numbers", and every number you encounter is a plain old real number. (However, *limits* may exist, for which you have a rigorous $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.)

Comment: in layman's terms, dx is the smallest positive number possible. (for visualization) does that help?

Comment: I mean suppose i have broken the curve into infinitely many rectangles and want to look at a particular rectangle.There i notice that the infinitely thin strips aren't perfect rectangles in my imagination,there is always some gaps.

Comment: I suppose relating to why rectangles are perfect i had answered the question in your last mse question.....   Regarding the Visualization, it entirely is our own lookout how we train our minds into believing what we have proved mathematically

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy workaround: forget infinitesimals, learn the definitions of limits, derivatives, integrals,... and work with them. I'll admit there may be some collateral damage: after several years of exercise and experience, you may start seeing those "infinitesimals", and which "gaps" you can safely ignore.

Alternative: you may study nonstandard analysis, making infinitesimals a rigorous notion. But there are several systems (Robinson, Nelson,...), none of them being trivial, all of them having their own pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes there is error/gap, however as the dx (infinitesimal) tends to 0 this error tends to 0 faster (quadratically, cubicly...). Yes you may be able to make dx smaller which is what i think you are saying by "cut it into smaller line" and thats correct because thats the whole idea of a Reimann Sum which is what approximates an integral as the dx basically becomes 0 (almost)

Answer (score -1):

Just like $x$ has no fixed value (it's variabel), so is $dx$. So you shouldn't be irritated by the fact that, even if you manage to visualise $dx$, there is still a "smaller $dx$". The way I visualise $dx$ is by contrasting it to $\Delta x$ with a looking glass that zooms in "infinitely deep". Here is a sketch:
[image]